# Jquery $.ajax statusCode Else

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

In a jquery Ajax call I am currently handling statusCode of 200 and 304. But I also have "Error" defined" To catch any Errors that could come back.

If there is a validation message related we return the status code of 400 - Bad Request.

This then falls into the "Error" function before falling into the statusCode "400" function I had defined. Which means two actions happen.

Ideally I would like to not define "Error" and "Success" and only define "statusCode" But what I need is to have a "Else" so that I don't need to declare every statusCode that exists only the 2-3 I want to handle differently.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "../API/Employees.svc/" + EmployeeId + "/Company/" + CompanyId,
        data: jsonString,
        statusCode: {
            200: function () { //Employee_Company saved now updated

                hideLoading();
                ShowAlertMessage(SaveSuccessful, 2000);
                $('#ManageEmployee').dialog('close');

            },
            304: function () { //Nothing to save to Employee_Company

                hideLoading();
                $('#ManageEmployee').dialog('close');

                if (NothingToChange_Employee) {
                    ShowAlertMessage(NothingToUpdate, 2000);
                } else {
                    ShowAlertMessage(SaveSuccessful, 2000);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            AjaxError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since the "complete" event is always fired you could simply get the status code from there and ignore the success and error functions

```
complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
    if(e.status === 200){

    }else if(e.status === 304){

    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work pretty well and is a good answer, though in my situation I ended up with actually using both success and failed. and do a similar if statement you have above in each.

Comment: complete() is now deprecated. Use done, fail, always replacement methods.

Answer (score 10):

This is what i'd use:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    switch (xhr.status) {
        case 401:
           // handle unauthorized
           break;
        default:
           AjaxError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery AJAX response `complete`, `success`, `error` have been deprecated. More up-to-date version with `.done`, `.fail`, `.always` promise instead.

On success `.always` has signature of `.done`, on failure it's signature changes to that of `.fail`. Using the `textStatus` you can grab the correct variable and return the body contents.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: frm.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    } )

    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "error" );
    })

    .always(function( data_jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_errorThrown ) {

        if (textStatus === 'success') {
            var jqXHR = jqXHR_errorThrown;
        } else {
            var jqXHR = data_jqXHR;
        }
        var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;

        switch (jqXHR.status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
            case 401:
            default:
                console.log(data);
                break;
        }   

});

jqxhr.always(function() {
    alert( "second complete" );
});
```

Comment: `jqXHR.error()` has been deprecated, not the `error` option to `jQuery.ajax()`. Don't know if it's implicitly deprecated along with it, but at least it's not documented as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the approach similar to your initial logic, I would continue passing a statusCode object.  However, you still know that "else" will fall in the realm of 4xx or 5xx type error codes.

So I would update your original code to:

```
var statusCodeResponses = {
    200: function () { //Employee_Company saved now updated

        hideLoading();
        ShowAlertMessage(SaveSuccessful, 2000);
        $('#ManageEmployee').dialog('close');

    },
    304: function () { //Nothing to save to Employee_Company

        hideLoading();
        $('#ManageEmployee').dialog('close');

        if (NothingToChange_Employee) {
            ShowAlertMessage(NothingToUpdate, 2000);
        } else {
           ShowAlertMessage(SaveSuccessful, 2000);
        }
    }
};

var genericElseFunction = function(response){
    // do whatever other action you wanted to take
};

for(var badResponseCode=400; badResponseCode<=599; badResponseCode++){
     statusCodeResponses[badResponseCode] = genericElseFunction;
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../API/Employees.svc/" + EmployeeId + "/Company/" + CompanyId,
    data: jsonString,
    statusCode: statusCodeResponses,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        AjaxError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```