# My Ajax post is not reaching the success

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

This is my ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AddUpdateConfigs",
    data: ({id: @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID, pathType: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(), threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(), valueType:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(), location: $('#txtbLocation').val(), limit: $('#txtbLimit').val(), config: $('#NewOrUpdate').val() }),
    dataType: JSON,
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("Data is duplicated");
        },
        405:function(){
            alert("Location Path is not correct");
        },
        406: function(){
            alert("Location Path has to be UNC path");
        },
        407: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    },
    success: function() 
    { 
        alert ("Success");
    }
});
```

It works good at the beggining and the `AddUpdateConfigs` function is called.
That function finished with `return Json(result);` where `result` is true.

And then my `success` is not firing because I'm not getting the `alert`

Any ideas please, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: try moving the curly brace from your success function up onto the same line as the function(). Sometimes javascript can imply semicolons. Good to rule this out early

Comment: I tried, not that lucky :(

Comment: Did you try handling `complete` event and getting the status code? this can be done like sayed in this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042040/jquery-ajax-statuscode-else)

Comment: If your action method truly is returning normally you could try to pull up fiddler and see the actual response sent back, or hit (F12) in the browser before the request and see if you getting any JS errors. You could also add a handlers on "error" and/or "complete" and see if those get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My success wasnt firing because I wasn't returning with a success, I was using a random error code because I thought I can just give them numbers like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, on your controller method you should use this:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Basically, if your action method does not return sensitive data, then it should be safe to allow the get.

However, `MVC` puts this in with `DenyGet` as the default to protect you against this attack. It makes you consider the implications of what data you are exposing, before you decide to expose it over `HTTP GET`.

In your AJAX, change your `ContentType` to

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

**JS:**

```
var queueMonitor = { id: @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID,
                     pathType: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(),
                     threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(),
                     valueType:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(),
                     location: $('#txtbLocation').val(),
                     limit: $('#txtbLimit').val(),
                     config: $('#NewOrUpdate').val() };

$.ajax({
            url: 'AddUpdateConfigs ',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ parameterName: queueMonitor }),
            success: function() { 
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddUpdateConfigs(QueueMonitor parameterName)  //Note parameter being same as that passed in AJAX Call.
{
   //Logic 

   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @AnnArbor87 Have u debugged your code by putting breakpoint in controller? Is it hit?

Comment: I saw your updated code, thats not the problem, the `Action` is called and the parameters received correctly.In the `Action` I do a DB query (which works) and then the return is hit. Seems like is not going back to make the Success, because the 'statusCodes' work when I insert some wrong values

Comment: Why are you concerned with "AllowGet" when the method is "POST"?

Comment: why dont you use `error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){ alert(textStatus);}` inside Ajax call. This will give you the exact error information.

Comment: @SanjeevRai My code is not full code...It just serves as the template to get the OP started.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function()
```

this should be

```
success: function(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it using:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUpdateConfigs(int id, string pathType, string threshold, string valueType, string location, int limit, string config)
{return new HttpStatusCodeResult(410, "New Data inserted");}
```

and:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AddUpdateConfigs",
        data: ({id: @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID, pathType: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(), threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(), valueType:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(), location: $('#txtbLocation').val(), limit: $('#txtbLimit').val(), config: $('#NewOrUpdate').val() }),
        dataType: 'application/json',
        statusCode: {
            404: function(){
                alert("Data is duplicated");
            },
            405:function(){
                alert("Location Path is not correct");
            },
            406: function(){
                alert("Location Path has to be UNC path");
            },
            407: function(error){
                alert(error);
            },
            410:function(result){
                alert("Item added correctly");

            },
            411:function(result){
                alert("Item updated correctly");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was because the form beaviour, closed before reaching the success/error event

`preventDefault()` solved it